# mongodb is not saving the data whaen run the program in second time

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, database, nosql

i started with this example : https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/#initial
everything is working fine , but i noticed that mongodb is not saving the data ! 
since when i run the progam in second time without saving the "customers" (in the example) , it returns null !

```
// save a couple of customers
repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));
```

your help is appreciated.
Edit:

```js
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.deleteAll();

        // save a couple of customers
        repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // fetch an individual customer
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

    }

}
```

```js
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

```js
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

Comment: the "//" are added by you to code snippet on SO or code is commented out?

Comment: yes , in second run i add "//" to see the data in first run saved or not

Comment: in fact , i mean when i disable the saving data in second run to check what is inside the db , it shows null !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all be sure you instruction are not commented out like in the snippet you posted.

Then be sure you removed the `repository.deleteAll();` from the example (next time provide the full code)

Then pay attention that `findByXxx` method of the interface `MongoRepository` will automatically create the code to search the object with the variable named `xxx` and specified value. Not sure what to expect if that variable is spelled wrong.

Comment: thank you , I put the code , i dont have repository.deleteall() . assume first i run the codes above , then i must have alice and bob in mongodb and it shows they are. but in second run i just want to check my database and run the program again with disabling those two line codes. it should show the resaults again , but it returns null !!1

Comment: Thank you , my problem as beginner was repository.deleteAll() and I removed that